# Side quest for Obelisk. Where is the Shrike Abyssal?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just started a game of ME3, and I got a side quest to find the Shrike Abyssal. However, the quest is not showing up in the Galaxy Map. Where should I be going?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a [forum thread on the official forums](http://social.bioware.com/forums/forum/1/topic/355/index/9653492/1#9660121) you need to finish the Palaven moon mission to get the Shrike Abyssal to show up on the galaxy map.

I did pay attention to this while playing myself and the system also only appeared for me after the Palaven mission.

Comment: I can confirm this. Shrike Abyssal did not appear on my map until I completed the Priority: Palaven mission.